# Как исключить поля структуры перед отправкой json на клиент?

Tags: golang, golang-struct

Есть такая структура:

```
type Build struct {
    ID          primitive.ObjectID `json:"ObjectID" bson:"_id"` // уникальный Id
    UserId      primitive.ObjectID `json:"userId" bson:"userId"` // id юзера для one-to-many
    Name        string             `json:"name" bson:"name"`
    Description string             `json:"description" bson:"description"`
    CreateTime  time.Time          `json:"createTime" bson:"createTime"`
    LifeTime    time.Duration      `json:"lifeTime" bson:"lifeTime"`
    DeadTime    time.Time          `json:"deadTime" bson:"deadTime"`
    IsActive    bool               `json:"isActive" bson:"isActive"`
    Location    GeoJson            `bson:"location" json:"location"`
}

type GeoJson struct {
    Type        string    `json:"type" bson:"type"`
    Coordinates []float64 `json:"coordinates"`
}
```

И такая функция:

```
func GetBuilds(response http.ResponseWriter, request *http.Request) {
    params := GetRequestParams(request.URL.Query())
    distance, _ := strconv.Atoi(params["distance"])
    latitude, _ := strconv.ParseFloat(params["latitude"], 64)
    longitude, _ := strconv.ParseFloat(params["longitude"], 64)
    var builds[]Build //инициализирую массив экземпляров модели
    var location = [2]float64{latitude, longitude} // создаю массив широты и долготы
    findOptions := options.Find()
    filter := bson.M{ // создаю гео-фильтр, и проверяю по параметру isActive
        "location": bson.M{
            "$nearSphere": bson.M{
                "$geometry": bson.M{
                    "type":        "Point",
                    "coordinates": location,
                },
                "$maxDistance": distance,
            },
        }, "isActive": true,
    }
    cur, _ := buildCollection.Find( //запрос к бд с фильтром
        context.TODO(),
        filter,
        findOptions)
    for cur.Next(context.TODO()) { // каждую найденную запись
        var elem Build
        _ = cur.Decode(&elem)                 //декодирую cursor в экземпляр модели
        if time.Now().Before(elem.DeadTime) { // если время уничтожения меньше текущего
            builds = append(builds, elem) // добавляю запись в массив записей
        } else { //иначе
            filter = bson.M{"_id": elem.ID}                     // фильтр по id записи
            update := bson.M{"$set": bson.M{"isActive": false}} // isActive устанавливаю на false
            _, _ = buildCollection.UpdateOne( // выполняю запрос
                context.TODO(),
                filter,
                update)
        }
    }

    _ = cur.Close(context.TODO()) // закрываю cursor
    if len(builds) > 0 {           // если количество записей больше 0
        response.Header().Add("Content-Type", "application/json")
        _ = json.NewEncoder(response).Encode(builds) // отправлю json на клиент
        return
    } else { //иначе
        response.WriteHeader(http.StatusNoContent) // отправлю статус-код 204
        return
    }
}
```

Но на клиент нужно отправлять не все поля структуры. Не нужны `IsActive`, `DeadTime`, `LifeTime`, `CreateTime`. Их можно убрать, если сделать такую аннотацию - `json:"-"`, но тогда это поле будет игнорироваться и при добавлении записи:

```
var build Build
_ = json.NewDecoder(request.Body).Decode(&build)// кодирую данные клиента в модель
_, err := buildCollection.InsertOne(context.TODO(), build)
```

Поэтому такой способ не подходит. Подумал, что можно создавать другую модель/структуру для исключения полей (именно для ответа):

```
type BuildToResponse struct {
    ID          primitive.ObjectID `json:"ObjectID" bson:"_id"`
    UserId      primitive.ObjectID `json:"userId" bson:"userId"`
    Name        string             `json:"name" bson:"name"`
    Description string             `json:"description" bson:"description"`
    Location    GeoJson            `bson:"location" json:"location"`
}
```

Но тут я сталкиваюсь с проблемой - в `BuildToResponse` нет поля DeadTime, и я не могу выполнить эту проверку `if time.Now().Before(elem.DeadTime)`. Что делают в таких случаях? Может есть сторонние сериализаторы, которые позволяют исключать поля из объекта, именно перед отправкой результата на клиент?

Comment: Аннотация `omitempty`, кажется, должна решить проблему?

Comment: @AlexSazonov The "omitempty" option specifies that the field should be omitted from the encoding if the field has an empty value, defined as false, 0, a nil pointer, a nil interface value, and any empty array, slice, map, or string. [из документации](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть несколько вариантов для решения проблемы.

```go
type User struct {
    Name string `json:"name"`
    Age  int    `json:"age"`
}
```

1. Использовать omitempty, если значение пустое.

```go
type User struct {
    Name string `json:"name,omtiempty"`
    Age  int    `json:"age,omitempty"`
}
```

```
User{"Alex", 0} --> {"name":"Alex"}
{"name":"Alex", 21} --> User{"Alex", 21}
```

2. Использовать другую структуру скрыв нужные поля тем или иным способом

```go
type UserResponse struct {
    Name string `json:"name"`
    age  int                  // ну или Age int `json:"-"`
}
```

3. Использовать свой метод MarshalJSON

```go
func (u *User) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    type userResponse struct {
        Name string
    }
    var reply userResponse
    reply.Name = u.Name
    return json.Marshal(&reply)
}
```